# Javascript memorygame pictures not turning

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

For a project I am currently working on making a game in HTML with JavaScript. In the final product the game was functioning perfect. But as I integrated the game in a website the game stopped functioning as it should.

I have made a memory game which you should click for turning to see the picture behind. Since I have integrated the game in a website the pictures are not turning anymore.

I have added my HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code.
I am using Flask as back-end server, and instead of an Apache server. So the Flask server is also handling as a Web Sever.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //variablen
  var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var w = $("#canvas").width();
  var h = $("#canvas").height();
  var cw = 15;
  var d = "right";
  var food;
  var score;
  var color = "green";
  var speed = 100;

  //snake
  var snake_array;

  //init
  function init() {
    d = "right";
    create_snake();
    create_food();
    score = "0";

    if (typeof game_loop != "undefined") clearInterval(game_loop);
    game_loop = setInterval(paint, speed);

  }

  init();

  //De snake wordt geboren
  function create_snake() {
    var length = 5;
    snake_array = [];
    for (var i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      snake_array.push({
        x: i,
        y: 0
      });
    }

  }

  //Voedsel balletjes plaatsen
  // plaatst voedsel ergens binnen het canvas?
  function create_food() {
    food = {
      x: Math.round(Math.random() * (w - cw) / cw),
      y: Math.round(Math.random() * (h - cw) / cw),
    };
  }

  //tekenen snake
  function paint() {
    //canvas
    ctx.fillStyle = "#d3f3ff";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, w, h);

    // positie van slang variablen
    var nx = snake_array[0].x;
    var ny = snake_array[0].y;

    //besturing
    if (d == 'right') nx++;
    else if (d == 'left') nx--;
    else if (d == 'up') ny--;
    else if (d == 'down') ny++;

    //botsen
    if (nx == -1 || nx == w / cw || ny == -1 || ny == h / cw || Check_Collision(nx, ny, snake_array)) {
      //init();
      //toevoegen eindscore
      $('#eindscore').html(score);
      //overlay tonen
      $('#overlay').fadeIn(speed = 300)
      return;
    }


    if (nx == food.x && ny == food.y) {
      var tail = {
        x: nx,
        y: ny
      };
      score++;
      //new voedsel moet verschijnen
      create_food();
    } else {
      tail = snake_array.pop();
      tail.x = nx;
      tail.y = ny;
    }

    snake_array.unshift(tail);

    for (var i = 0; i < snake_array.length; i++) {
      var c = snake_array[i];
      paint_cell(c.x, c.y);
    }
    //teken  groeien slang
    paint_cell(food.x, food.y);

    //score controle
    checkscore(score);

    //score tonen
    $('#score').html('Je score: ' + score)
  }


  function paint_cell(x, y) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(x * cw, y * cw, cw, cw);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
    ctx.strokeRect(x * cw, y * cw, cw, cw);
  }

  function Check_Collision(x, y, SnakeArray) {
    for (var I = 0; I < snake_array.Length; I++) {
      if (array[I.x == x && snake_array[I].y == y])
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  function checkscore(score) {
    if (localStorage.getItem('eindscore') === null) {
      //zonder score
      localStorage.setItem('eindscore', score);
    } else {
      //score al aanwezig
      if (score > localStorage.getItem('eindscore')) {
        localStorage.setItem('eindscore', score);
      }
    }
    $('#eind_score').html('Score: ' + localStorage.eindscore);
  }


  //slang besturen
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if (key == "37" && d != "right") d = "left";
    else if (key == "38" && d != "down") d = "up";
    else if (key == "39" && d != "left") d = "right";
    else if (key == "40" && d != "up") d = "down";
  })
});

function resetscore() {
  localStorage.eind_score = 0;
  //
  eindscorediv = document.getElementById('eind_score');
  eindscorediv.innerHTML = 'Eind Score: 0'
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#canvas-game {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
  width: 612px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: Solid 1px #ebe5e5;
  height: 385px;
  position: relative;
}

#game-statistic {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
  width: 612px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#statistic-left,
#statistic-right {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: left;
}

#statistic-right {
  float: right;
}

.bold-text {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.congrats-message {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
}

.box-picture {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  border: solid 1px #ebe5e5;
  display: none;
}

.box-picture>img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
}

.box-cover-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

.box-cover {
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: url(../static/MemoryGame/game-images/image-cover.jpg) no-repeat;
  border: solid 1px #ebe5e5;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#game-message {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: orangered;
  padding: 15px;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 612px;
  display: none;
}

#btnRestart {
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background: #66C835;
  text-decoration: uppercase;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/**** Als het scherm kleinder is dan 640px ****/

@media (max-width: 640px) {
  #canvas-game {
    width: 385px;
    height: 348px;
  }
  .box-picture,
  .box-picture>img,
  .box-cover {
    width: 75px;
    height: 56px;
  }
  .box-cover {
    background: url(../static/MemoryGame/game-images/image-cover-75.jpg) no-repeat;
  }
  #game-statistic {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  #game-message,
  #game-statistic {
    width: 385px;
  }
}


/**** Als het scherm kleinder is dan 640px 320px ****/

@media (max-width: 320px) {
  #canvas-game {
    width: 156px;
    height: 390px;
  }
  .box-picture,
  .box-picture>img,
  .box-cover {
    width: 50px;
    height: 38px;
  }
  .box-cover {
    background: url(../static/MemoryGame/game-images/image-cover-50.jpg) no-repeat;
  }
  #game-statistic {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  #game-message,
  #game-statistic {
    width: 156px;
  }
  #statistic-left,
  #statistic-right {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" charset="utf-8">
  <title>Memory_Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/TulipAir.css">
  <link href="../static/MemoryGame.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../static/MemoryGame.js"></script>
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Titel Website -->
  <h1 id="TextCenter">Welkom bij Tulip Air</h1>
  <!-- Navigatie bar -->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Media">Media</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Chat">Chat</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Kaart">Reisinformatie</a></li>
    <li><a href="/VliegtuigInformatie">Vliegtuig Informatie</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="/Games">Games</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Webshop">Webshop</a></li>
    <li id="FloatRight"><a href="/Admin">Admin</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="games">
    <a href="/Snake"><img src="../static/snake.png"></a>
    <a href="/MemoryGame"><img src="../static/MemoryGame.jpg"></a>
  </div>

  <div>

    <div id="canvas-game">
      <div id="game-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="game-statistic">
      <div id="statistic-left">No of Clicks: <span id="no-of-clicks" class="bold-text">0</span></div>
      <div id="statistic-right">Correct Guess: <span id="correct-guess" class="bold-text">0</span></div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="game-message">
      <div class="congrats-message">Wooosh, you succesfully landed! :)</div>
      <button id="btnRestart" type="button">Speel opnieuw</button>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>


<footer>
  <p id="TextCenter">© Tulip Air</p>
</footer>

</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your example doesn't even work. Maybe while narrowing down the problem you find a solution for it.

Comment: Did you check the console for error messages? After moving it to a different server it's possible some resources aren't getting loaded.

Comment: You have `var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];` but there's no `id="canvas"` in your HTML.

Comment: @MattBurland Unfortunately there are no errors in the console

Comment: @Barmar the id is called id="canvas-game" I am going to look what the results are when changing to id="canvas"

Comment: @Wiresh That's a `<div>`, shouldn't it be `<canvas>`?

Comment: @Barmar the weird thing is that it works before integrating it into my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off all I am really thankful for your quick answers. This is mine first Stack Overflow post, and I found the solution within half an hour. :)

When I whas integrating the code in mine website I deleted a piece of code

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

The code from above helps the picture to move with a 3d transition. After I was deleting unnecessary code I saw that something was missing. I have putted the code back, and everything does work again :)